# My simple calculation with Bigintegers are not working

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to calculate this: 2894135^3787313 mod 4028033

As you can see below i tried to use the BigInteger because i have really huge numbers.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BigInteger extends Number implements Comparable<BigInteger>
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  BigInteger result=new BigInteger(Math.pow(2894135,3787313) % 4028033);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> /tmp/java_Wcf144/BigInteger.java:19: error: BigInteger is not abstract
>   and does not override abstract method doubleValue() in Number public
>   class BigInteger extends Number implements Comparable
>          ^ /tmp/java_Wcf144/BigInteger.java:24: error: constructor BigInteger in class BigInteger cannot be applied to given types;
>   BigInteger result=new BigInteger(Math.pow(2894135,3787313) % 4028033);
>                       ^   required: no arguments   found: double   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 2 errors

Comment: rename your class to something else other than `BigInteger`

Comment: Aside from anything else, you're trying to do all the arithmetic *first*, and then convert the *result* to `BigInteger`. That isn't going to work. You should be doing *all the arithmetic* in `BigInteger`. And yes, as Reimeus says, you really don't want to be declaring your own class as `BigInteger`...

Comment: But *don't* rename it to Biginteger (as in your title).

Comment: Not sure if you realize this, but `2894135 ^ 3787313` is a _really_ **big** number. Basically, you cannot calculate that expression. Even `BigInteger` won't help you here...

Comment: no chance for calculating that? I mean wolframalpha can do it, but i need to run this calculation with 3000 different numbers. I will read the numbers from a txt file

Comment: Wolfram will do an approximation to a certain number of digits. It won't calculate all 25 million digits...

Comment: Still, "funny" question. And it taught me an important lesson: "even when you are in a hurry to answer; read the question carefully; and check all its details."

Comment: Ah nice, I didn't know about `modPow()`. Because if you'd first try to calculate `2894135 ^ 3787313` and then do the modulo, you'd be in trouble...

Comment: @radoh: calculating that number is not extremely slow. Turning it into a string is (turning a 2 million digit value into a string took a few minutes in my highly optimized Delphi BigInteger implementation, calculating it only a few seconds). But using modPow() instead of pow() will make both calculating and displaying a ***lot*** faster. And BigIntegers can easily handle 25 million digits.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis hmm, I stand corrected. It took ~30 seconds to calculate it on my machine, which is much less than I would've anticipated. To be honest, at first I expected the number to have a lot more digits (even though 25mil is a lot already).

Comment: @radoh: Try to do a `.toString()` on it. I guess you'll have time to make and drink a cup of coffee (or two) before it is finished. Don't print it, though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get wrong answer even after solving the errors because `Math.pow(2894135,3787313)`, This will cause `overflow` in `double` and it will return largest possible value of double `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

So you need to do all operations after converting them into `BigInteger`.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        BigInteger a=BigInteger.valueOf(2894135);
        BigInteger b=BigInteger.valueOf(3787313);
        BigInteger m=BigInteger.valueOf(4028033);
        BigInteger result=a.modPow(b,m); //calculates a^b %m
        System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
 If you want to do this in more optimized way then you can use concept of **[Modular Exponentiation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/)**. This will give output in `O(log(exponent))` complexity. Here you can't use bigger values because it may cause `overflow` in `long` which ends up in giving wrong result.

Code:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        long a=2894135;
        long b=3787313;
        long m=4028033;

        long result=modularExponentiation(a,b,m);
        System.out.println(result);
  }

    static long modularExponentiation(long a,long b,long m)
    {
        long result=1;
        while(b>0)
        {
            if(b % 2 ==1)
                result=(result * a)%m;
            a=(a*a)%m;
            b=b/2;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this! Thank you very much for your time, i got the the correct result :)

Comment: Although you came in a bit later; you where the first one to give the fully correct answer. My upvote for that!

Comment: AFAIK, modular exponentiation is what `BigInteger.modPow` uses too. But of course for BigIntegers, not for longs.

Comment: Ahh @RudyVelthuis , I didn't know that `BigInteger.modPow` uses `modular exponentiation`. Thanks for informing me. 

P.S: Though that thought came in my mind while writing the answer that It should be using it. :P

Answer (score 3):

You have not implemented `doubleValue()` method in your class.
And you also need to rename your main class with some other name , Big Integer is a seperate object.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues: the first one about the mis-use of the BigInteger class.

you declared your **own** BigInteger class, which sorry doesn't make much sense. If you want to be able to work with arbitrary sized **Integer** values; use the **existing** [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

From there:

```
BigInteger result=new BigInteger(Math.pow(2894135,3787313) % 4028033);
```

You are **not** computing **with** BigInteger objects.

You are using int literals, to compute a value; and the result of that you intend to use as ctor argument for creating a single BigInteger.

You could go for:

```
BigInteger op1 = new BigInteger(2894135)
BigInteger op2 = new BigInteger(3787313);
BigInteger op3 = new BigInteger(4028033);
BigInteger result = op1.modpow(op2, op3);
```

instead. Depending on the numbers you intend to use; you might or might not be able to do the "pow" calculation as you did before; using Math.pow() and work on **double** literals. But the above will work for **any** numbers that fitting into the JVM.

Comment: also the constructor `BigInter(long/double)` isn't working. use `BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(2894135,3787313))`

Comment: It's true, but this is not what the error is about.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The code from Sanket Makani below solved all my problem and did this huge calculation!

Comment: Well the real real initial problem is as @Sushobh Nadiger noted. He is extending the `Number` class. That class has an abstract function `doubleValue()` which the OP's class first needs to override before it can compile.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even want to create a BigInteger class.

BigInteger is already defined in Java, use it

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Also, do all the operations on BigInteger, rather than converting them to BigInteger at the end.

Abhi